# How to migrate a chart from Highcharts Demo to Highcharts Cloud

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Perhaps others have seen the amazing [Force-Directed Network Graph](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/network-graph) demo which I would dearly love to adapt to my own ends. However, simply copying the code over doesn't seem to be enough.

I'm no longer using the inline-defined data but rather data coming from a Google Sheets file. And I've morphed the code so that it contains more columns in the data. Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6w5d2nu3/2/) though without the Google Sheets connection. 
(I have tried the Google Sheets connection there but it doesn't work -- for reasons yet to be discovered. The connection is public if anyone wants to fiddle.)

So here's the code that I've dumped into the "Custom Code" panel in the "Customize" section of Highcharts Cloud.

```
Highcharts.addEvent(
    Highcharts.seriesTypes.networkgraph, 'afterSetOptions',
    function (e) {
        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
            i = 0,
            nodes = {};
        e.options.data.forEach(function (link) {
            if (link[0] === 'Keyword Research') {
                nodes['Keyword Research'] = {
                    id: 'Keyword Research',
                    marker: { radius: link[2] }
                };
                nodes[link[1]] = {
                    id: link[1], marker: { radius: link[2] }, color: colors[i++]
                };
            }
            else if
                (nodes[link[0]] && nodes[link[0]].color) {
                nodes[link[1]] = {
                    id: link[1], color: nodes[link[0]].color
                };
            }
        });
        e.options.nodes = Object.keys(nodes).map(function (id) { return nodes[id]; });
    }
);
Highcharts.chart('highcharts-container',
    {
        chart: { type: 'networkgraph', height: '100%' },
        title: { text: 'The Indo-European Language Tree' },
        subtitle: { text: 'A Force-Directed Network Graph in Highcharts' },
        plotOptions: { networkgraph: { keys: ['from', 'to'], layoutAlgorithm: { enableSimulation: true, friction: -0.9 } } },
        series: [{
            dataLabels: { enabled: true, linkFormat: '' },
            "data": {
                "googleSpreadsheetKey": "1kQKkN4auaxsgwms057FkJ7l5g3mhBjR5vp5PPpStDBQ",
                "dataRefreshRate": false,
                "enablePolling": true,
                "startRow": "2",
                "endRow": "14",
                "startColumn": "1",
                "endColumn": "3"
              }
        }]
    }
);
```

It'd be great to find out how to make it work.

**LATER**

Setup for GoogleDrive included as a comment in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I have not solved this 100%, but have fixed one issue which may lead you to get an answer. You have your `data` element inside `series`, but when looking at the [highcharts api](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.googleSpreadsheetKey) for googleSpreadsheetKey, they have put it outside series. So, try the following. When I do, I get CORS error in the console.

```
Highcharts.addEvent(
    Highcharts.seriesTypes.networkgraph, 'afterSetOptions',
    function (e) {
        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
            i = 0,
            nodes = {};
        e.options.data.forEach(function (link) {
            if (link[0] === 'Keyword Research') {
                nodes['Keyword Research'] = {
                    id: 'Keyword Research',
                    marker: { radius: link[2] }
                };
                nodes[link[1]] = {
                    id: link[1], marker: { radius: link[2] }, color: colors[i++]
                };
            }
            else if
                (nodes[link[0]] && nodes[link[0]].color) {
                nodes[link[1]] = {
                    id: link[1], color: nodes[link[0]].color
                };
            }
        });
        e.options.nodes = Object.keys(nodes).map(function (id) { return nodes[id]; });
    }
);

Highcharts.chart('highcharts-container',
{
    chart: { type: 'networkgraph', height: '100%' },
    title: { text: 'The Indo-European Language Tree' },
    subtitle: { text: 'A Force-Directed Network Graph in Highcharts' },
    plotOptions: { networkgraph: { keys: ['from', 'to'], layoutAlgorithm: { enableSimulation: true, friction: -0.9 } } },
    series: [{
        dataLabels: { enabled: true, linkFormat: '' }
    }],
    "data": {
        "googleSpreadsheetKey": "1kQKkN4auaxsgwms057FkJ7l5g3mhBjR5vp5PPpStDBQ",
        "dataRefreshRate": false,
        "enablePolling": true,
        "startRow": "2",
        "endRow": "14",
        "startColumn": "1",
        "endColumn": "3"
      }
});
```

Comment: Certainly a step in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts Cloud **doesn't support force directed graph** for now.

This series requires **network graph module** (https://code.highcharts.com/modules/networkgraph.js) which is not imported for charts created in Cloud. Here's the list of imported scripts:

```
  var scripts = [
    "highcharts.js",
    "modules/stock.js",
    "highcharts-more.js",
    "highcharts-3d.js",
    "modules/data.js",
    "modules/exporting.js",
    "modules/funnel.js",
    "modules/solid-gauge.js",
    "modules/export-data.js",
    "modules/accessibility.js",
    "modules/annotations.js"
  ];
```